# Raspberry Pi 4 8GB not showing up on network and isn't able to transfer files

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, samba, file-sharing

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 8gb that I am using as a local nas. When I got it I connected it to wifi, installed samba and got it configured - it worked perfectly (was accessible/discoverable/modifiable) by all windows 10 computers connected to it and on the network. However, I recently got a TP link network switch (TL-SG105) so I can connect my Pi to ethernet, while still having my main pc connected to ethernet as well. Now it's not showing up as a computer on the network (it still can access the internet however), even though it is plugged into ethernet. I don’t know what to do or how to fix it. The cable running from the switch to the Pi is a Cat 5E, and the cable running from the google router to the switch is a Cat 5

Comment: First thought is you do not have the correct Ethernet cable.  The Pi boards are very fussy in that they need all pins connected for Gigabit speed and does not properly support fallback to slower speeds.  Check you have a Cat-6 cable or Cat-5e with all pins connected (all 8 of them)  - also can you add the type of switch to you question (use edit not a comment) please?  You may also be able to set your switch port speed down to 100Mbs as a temporary measure till you get the correct cable.

Comment: Does your switch support GigaBit Ethernet?

Comment: Andrew I edited the question with more info